# BoundingRectWithSize - Choosing Font & Font Size Used

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, uibutton, uilabel

I am using BoundingRectWithSize to get back a CGRect that will appropriately fix my text. 
I previously had this code.

```
var maximumLabelSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: view.bounds.width-5, height: 150)
         var maximumLabelSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: view.bounds.width-5, height: 150)
    var labelRect: CGRect = (matches[indexPath.item].name as NSString).boundingRectWithSize(maximumLabelSize, options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(16)], context: nil)
```

When changing the font to HelviticaNeue-Bold many of my labels were not displaying their full screens. My hypothesis was that since I changed the font to bold the text could no longer fit within their bounding CGRects and as a result cutting the strings short.

My proposed fix was to edit the code that created the initial appropriate bounding CGRect for my text to take into account the bold nature of the text. This was my attempt.

```
var labelRect: CGRect = (matches[indexPath.item].name as NSString).boundingRectWithSize(maximumLabelSize, options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 16)], context: nil)
```

I am getting an error that my supplied arguments are incorrect.

```
Cannot invoke 'boundingRectWithSize' with an argument list of type '(CGSize, options: NSStringDrawingOptions, attributes: [String : UIFont?], context: nil)'
```

According to the iOS Developer Library these are the appropriate parameters.

```
func boundingRectWithSize(_ size: CGSize,
                  options options: NSStringDrawingOptions,
               attributes attributes: [String : AnyObject]?,
                  context context: NSStringDrawingContext?) -> CGRect
```

The conflict is within attributes, obviously the area I changed, but at least this confirms it. I am unsure of how to pursue the solution any further. Any help understanding this would be well appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Upon further analyzing the contrast between my own supplied boundingRectWithSize arguments and the ones listed within the iOS Developer Library, I wondered what would happen if I casted the UIFont to an AnyObject.

```
var labelRect: CGRect = (matches[indexPath.item].name as NSString).boundingRectWithSize(maximumLabelSize, options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 16) as! AnyObject], context: nil)
```

The attributes argument of boundingRectWithSize accepts the type [String : AnyObject] while I supposedly supply [String : UIFont?]. I casted my UIFont? to AnyObject. This silenced the error and also solved my problem. Bolded text is no longer cut short. Solved.

Answer (score 0):

UIFont(name, size) has an "Optional" output. And, boundingRectWithSize does not accept the optional output of UIFont with a name. Try this: it works.

```
if let font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 16) {
        var labelRect2: CGRect = ("Random String" as NSString).boundingRectWithSize(maximumLabelSize, options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font], context: nil)

}
```

Comment: This silenced the error but it did not cease the bolded text from being cut off. The 'attributes' argument within the original boundingRectWithSize call requests type [String: AnyObject] which `[NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(16)]` satisfies. How is `UIFont.systemFontOfSize( 16)` of type AnyObject while `UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 16)` is of type UIFont? Dealing with the optional did silence the error, although it does not stop the bounding box from being incorrect.

Comment: The only difference I can key in on would be the type difference.. Supposed type difference. I am unsure of whether or not your optional fix caused the argument to change from UIFont to AnyObject. Then the error could reside somewhere else.

Comment: Both are of the same type actually, if you print objects of both of them. you will get :

<UICTFont: 0x79056cb0> font-family: ".HelveticaNeueInterface-Regular"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 16.00pt

Optional(<UICTFont: 0x7916bec0> font-family: "Helvetica Neue"; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-size: 16.00pt)

Moreover, anyobject is not a type, but rather a protocol that can represent an instance of any class type. If you know C/C++, consider it equivalent to void * in C for holding any pointer, only difference here is that it holder any Object.

Comment: As to the problem you are facing w.r.t text size getting cut, can you please update your question with an "update" section and show us the new code that you are using?

Comment: To the second answer you posted. Yeap, it does solve the problem. Typcasting shouldn't matter here, infact if you try UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 16) as! UIFont, it should still work. The main thing is to get away with optionals. Well done, your solution seems more elegant.

Comment: Although I do not understand my solution. Using your solution, the text gets cut. Though if I cast it as an AnyObject, the bounding box is the correct size. I am not sure how casting it as an AnyObject changes things. They are still technically the same type, so why does one method produce an incorrect rectangle while the other is the proper size?

Comment: I am not seeing the same problem:
        println(labelRect)
        println(labelRect2)
       
gives output:
(0.0, 0.0, 269.744, 19.088)
(0.0, 0.0, 281.168, 19.072)

So this is giving me different box for the same Text but different fonts.